# JPA CrudRepository save() not populating primary key after save

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have very strange issue here. I am using composite primary key with `@IdClass` in my entities. It is working fine in every case, except save. After saving the entity, JPA is not firing `SELECT` query to select inserted data, and not merging the result. Though data is getting saved in database successfully. Also there are no errors. Below is some of the code which can help in debugging the issue:

AbstractEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1191422925622832672L;

    /** The id. */
    private String id;

    ...

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ...
}
```

PrimaryKey.java

```
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    /** The id. */
    private String id;

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Convert(converter = CryptoConverter.class)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ...
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, PrimaryKey> {
}
```

I have `BigInt autoIncrement` Id in database as primary key. But I want to expose it in encrypted form to outside world, so I have used `@Converter` to encrypt and decrypt it.

When I invoke `userRepository.save(userEntity)` from `UserService`, it persists the data, but does not return generated id from database.

How can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**
I have hosted demo project with this functionality [here](https://github.com/jigneshkhatri/spring-boot-with-db-key-encryption).

Comment: Try `userRepository.flush()` after `userRepository.save(userEntity)`, then check for the generated id.

Comment: But it was working earlier, before I used `@IdClass`. And `.flush()` method is not there in `CrudRepository` class.

Comment: Tried with `.flush()` from `JpaRepository`, but with no success.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example on Github?

Comment: Also, how do you check the id? Are you using `User savedEntity=userRepository.save(userEntity); savedEntity....getId()`?

Comment: That way I won't get Id I know, as Transaction would only get commit once it is returned from service method (I use `@Transactional` on service methods). But outside that too (on client side or in controller), I am getting id as null.

Comment: Do you know how actually Id is populated by JPA, once entity is saved?

Comment: Actually that's the way to get it, please try. Can you post the code that gets the id?

Comment: I tried everything. Still no clues. I know there is some issue with `@IdClass`, but don't know what and why.

Comment: I have updated the description of this question. I have hosted the demo project on GitHub. Here is the link for it - https://github.com/jigneshkhatri/spring-boot-with-db-key-encryption

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not seeing anywhere in your code, you need to specify `Id`, the strategy type and the column on the database.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "applicant_id")
```